After Keycloak integration with Liferay, I am getting error
I have done the Keycloak integration with Liferay 7.4 after the portal migration from 7.2 to 7.4. But when I start the server, I get this error:
2024-05-29 06:45:01.537 ERROR [CM Configuration Updater (ManagedServiceFactory Update: factoryPid=[com.liferay.portal.security.sso.openid.connect.internal.configuration.OpenIdConnectProviderConfiguration])][BatchingBatch:139] HHH000315: Exception executing batch [org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update OAuthClientASLocalMetadata set mvccVersion=?, modifiedDate=? where oAuthClientASLocalMetadataId=? and mvccVersion=?], SQL: update OAuthClientASLocalMetadata set mvccVersion=?, modifiedDate=? where oAuthClientASLocalMetadataId=? and mvccVersion=?

The Keycloak login screen is not appearing, suspecting this is related to this error.
Also, getting error :
    2024-05-29 13:14:40.374 ERROR [http-nio-9015-exec-9][VirtualHostFilter:53] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.liferay.portal.security.sso.openid.connect.internal.servlet.filter.auto.login.OpenIdConnectAutoLoginFilter.isFilterEnabled(OpenIdConnectAutoLoginFilter.java:52) ~[?:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:78) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:138) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:236) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:40) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:138) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:116) [bundleFile:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:40) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:189) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:189) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at com.liferay.portal.url.rewrite.filter.internal.URLRewriteFilter.processFilter(URLRewriteFilter.java:86) [bundleFile:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:40) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:189) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:95) [portal-kernel.jar:?]
        at com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.proxy.FilterWrapper.doFilter(FilterWrapper.java:69) [com.liferay.shielded.container.impl.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.83]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.83]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]


Have you tried creating the configuration manually again, there might be differences in the configuration between 7.2 and 7.4.

No, but I haven't find any SSO configuration difference between 7.2 and 7.4 @KristofMols
